# $(x+1)^n \equiv x^n +1 \mod n$ iff $n$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Prove that the polynomial identity $(x+1)^n \equiv x^n +1 \mod n$ holds iff $n$ is prime.

One direction is easy: Assume that $n$ is prime. By the binomial theorem we have $(x+1)^n = \sum^{n}_{k=0} {n\choose k} x^k$, and since $n$ is prime, for every $1\leq k\leq n-1$ we have ${n\choose k} = 0 \mod n$.

I'm not sure about the other direction- we know that

$(x+1)^n - (x^n +1) \equiv \sum^{n-1}_{k=1} {n\choose k} x^k \equiv 0 \mod n$,

and it seems to me that I need to show that if $n$ is not prime then there is some non-zero coefficient for the above polynomial, but I am not sure how to do this, or how exactly this contradicts the above (for example $x^2 -x$ is always zero over the binary field, but has non-zero coefficients).

Comment: About your last comment: it is sufficient to show that $x^n+1$ and $(x+1)^n$ have different coefficients modulo $n$. The reason for this is that two polynomials being equal isn't defined by them giving the same function on whatever ring they're defined over, but rather by them having the same coefficients. So $x^2-x$ and $0$ are different polynomials over the binary field, even though they both give the $0$-function on the binary field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is prime dividing $n$; let $p^k$ be the largest power of $p$ dividing $n$. Then $p^k$ does not divide $\binom{n}{p}$ (hint: consider the number of times $p$ appears on the numerator and on the denominator of $\frac{n \times (n-1) \times \dots \times (n-p+1)}{p!}$), and so the coefficient of $x^p$ is not zero in $(x+1)^n$.

---

You may be interested in the AKS primality test, by the way, of which this is a specific instance. See https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf for the paper, in which Lemma 2.1 is a generalisation of what you want to prove.