# Prove that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p \mod p$ where $p$ is a prime.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-theorem

Let $p$ be a prime, we want to prove that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p \mod p$.
The left handside looks like something we can throw the binomial theorem at, also in the previous proof the book asked to prove that $p|\binom{p}{k}$ for all natural numbers $k$ except $0$ and $p$. So we then know that $\binom{p}{k} \equiv 0 \mod p$ for k unequal to $0$ and to p$.

$$(x+y)^p=\sum^p_{k=0} \binom{p}{k} x^{p-k} y^k \equiv \binom{p}{p}x^{p-p}y^p+  \binom{p}{0}x^{p-0}y^0 \mod p $$
 Since all other terms are congruent to $0$.
This can be simplified to:

$$(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p\mod p $$

Alternatively, for a way shorter proof we can just note that for any prime $p$ we have that $a^p \equiv a \mod p$ by Fermat's little theorem. $$ (x+y)^p \equiv x+y \mod p \equiv x^p +y^p \mod p$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Of course, it is Fermat little theorem

Comment: Note that $p\mid{ p\choose k}$ only for $0<k<n$

Comment: you got the binomial formula wrong. Fix that and then apply @HagenvonEitzen's hint.

Comment: OP, if you know that $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$, then the equality follows immediately; simply apply it to $(x+y)^p$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648561/x1n-equiv-xn-1-mod-n-iff-n-is-prime

Comment: there is a good hint there

Comment: I corrected the mistakes in the binomial theorem and worked with the hint.

Comment: yes but then you can apply it again @TonyK

Comment: See my new edited question

Comment: your edit is correct

Comment: Primality of $p$ is not required.

Comment: Yes I thought so too when I first tackled the problem, however for Fermat's little theorem it is and for divisibility of $\binom{p}{k}$  by $p$ too. For instance consider $p=4$ then $\binom{4}{2}=6$ and $4 \not | 6 $. So $p \not | \binom{p}{k}$